# How can I remove the quick launch and ribbon row for all pages without affecting the _layouts views?

Tags: css, custom

I would like to hide these features on the Site pages, but not have them be hidden when in a folder (when I go to View All Site Content, ie _layouts/viewlsts.aspx).

If I add some css to the default.master file, it reoves the quick launch and top ribbon from the home page, but also from the library views.

Is there a better place to add this css so that it only affects the SitePages and not the libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried creating two separate master pages (one with CSS, one without) and set System Master Page and Custom Master page accordingly?

Comment: How can I set the system master page? I don't have sharepoint designer.

Answer (score 1):

sharepoint has 2 master page, system and site, views and all other admin related pages uses system master page, sites pages uses site master page, make changes accordingly.

see following screenshots, first screen shows site collection features need to be activated at site collection level, second screen show feature need to be activated at site level and then you will be able to see "master" page option.

[image: site collection]

[image: site features]

[image]

[image: master page settings]

Comment: Ah, that would definitely be the solution! When I go to Site Settings > Galleries > Master Pages, I see only one master page that seems to be controlling both the system and site pages. Do I need to assign either the system pages or site pages to a different master page? Or should I be looking somewhere else for a system or site master page that would override the other? Thanks!

Comment: yes, in most of the cases, we create 2 master page, one for site and second for the system administration pages.

Comment: In few cases like "Blog" site template, if you want to customize look n feel, you have to update system master page.

Comment: Do you by chance know how to assign the system master page? I'm working without sharepoint designer and am not seeing where I can do that.

Comment: I have added a screenshot in my original reply. currently "seattle" is being used as both system and site master page.

Comment: @edgar: Are you on team site? You'd need Publishing Site Collection feature enabled. Or use CSOM to set it via code.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the hep Shafaqat. Unfortunately I can't get to that page. I don't have Master Page listed under Look and Feel in my Site Settings, and Galleries > Master Pages just shows a list of the available master pages, without a way to assign one to system pages. I guess I can't have separate master pages.

Comment: make sure you have activated "publishing feature" on site collection and site level. see pictures. original reply updated with more screenshots.